# how do I connect to postgresql with psql from powershell?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL 13 on Windows 10 using the EDB installer and it seems to work fine. I can connect easily with `psql` in the included `SQL Shell` application. However, I can not connect from powershell:

```
~> psql -U postgres -h localhost
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any permutation of `psql` command line switches yields the same result. I checked `pg_hba.conf` and it looks sane - all local connections are allowed. All the search results for the error code above on the internet assume the server is not running but it *is* running just fine (see `SQL Shell` above). Within that shell, all the `postgres` tables are visible, etc. What do I need to do to connect `psql` to the server on localhost from powershell?

Default installed `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

The IPv4 line above should cover me in powershell? Yes? tcp connections are allowed in `postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

Long time linux PostgreSQL user, first time in powershell on Windows, though...

Comment: I know it's foolish! but did you restart the server after changes in ph_hba and postgresql.conf ?
Start -> Control panel -> Administration -> Services -> postgresql-x64-12 - start or restart

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe nothing in the log files though I did sort it out early this morning (see below).

Comment: @NikhilB yes, I restarted the service several times just to be sure!

Comment: Sorry, yes, the log file cannot show that, since it is a network problem. Does `SHOW listen_addresses;` show the correct value? Other than that, it may be a firewall problem.

Answer (score 1):

This morning I found the problem - the EDB installer had setup the postgres service to run on port 5433. After a couple of decades or running it on 5432 I didn't even notice that the number was different in `postgresql.conf`. It was late...

Something else must be running on 5432. Will check later on.